# Is there any way to create a custom PS1 for particular terminal profile

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, ps1

Since I find the custom terminal a bit bland, I like using the PS1 variable to make it more informative, and use a background image and custom text colours. I like the profile functionality, so I have a couple of profiles, but they all use the same PS1 variable. Is there any wya to create a custom PS1 for each profile?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to query the profile itself, but in newer gnome-terminal versions (and several other emulators) you can query the colors using commands like e.g. `xtermcontrol --get-fg` for the foreground, and similar options for the other colors. You can branch based on its output in `.bashrc` to set up different `PS1`.

Your gnome-terminal might be too old for this, though, since you mention you use background images which are no longer supported by recent gnome-terminal versions.